# laravel mysql database migrate:install error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

After going through some of basic laravel codes, i tried my hands on with migrations. the following is my app\config\databast.php file -

```
 return array(

        'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

        'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

            'sqlite' => array(
                'driver'   => 'sqlite',
                'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
                'prefix'   => '',
            ),

            'mysql' => array(
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'myproject',
                'database'  => 'myproj',
                'username'  => 'root',
                'password'  => '',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ),

            'pgsql' => array(
                'driver'   => 'pgsql',
                'host'     => 'myproject',
                'database' => 'myproj',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'charset'  => 'utf8',
                'prefix'   => '',
                'schema'   => 'public',
            ),

            'sqlsrv' => array(
                'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
                'host'     => 'myproject',
                'database' => 'database',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'prefix'   => '',
            ),

        ),

        'migrations' => 'migrations',

        'redis' => array(

            'cluster' => true,

            'default' => array(
                'host'     => '127.0.0.2',
                'port'     => 6379,
                'database' => 0,
            ),

        ),

    );
```

as you can see, default is mysql database. then in command prompt i tried this.

```
php artisan migrate:make users
```

the output was -

```
created migration: 2013_08_05_110148_users
Generating optimized class loader
```

then i tried this

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

but i got the error like this 
[image]

you can see its showing "Host medismoCRM is not allowed to connect to this server." medismoCRM is another project which i had done in mysql server. So i checked the host file. the lines in host file are like this -

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       medismoCRM
127.0.0.2       myproject
```

so both medismoCRM and current project myproject are with different IP. then also i checked httpd-vhosts.conf file in apache. there also i have 2 different hosts like this-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/laravel-master/public/"
    ServerName myproject
    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/laravel-master/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.2
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/medismoCRM/"
    ServerName medismoCRM
    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/medismoCRM/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

so can anyone tell why that error is coming in command prompt when i try for php artisan migrate:install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/config/app.php`, make sure you set `'url' => 'http://myproject'`

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have installed PDO in `phpinfo()` ?

Create a file `phpinfo.php` and put into file `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Example of picture: http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/images/pdo_mysql.PNG

Make sure on `php.ini` are loaded PDO driver, check for PDO line `extension=php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll` If there aren't about PDO extension, a driver PDO  will not loading.

Check PDO connection:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myproj', 'root', '');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from users') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Create on a new file and check is your PDO with database really works.

Comment: yes, i checked this. and PDO is enabled. and also that extension is enabled too.

Comment: You write `app\config\databast.php` instead `app\config\database.php`. Is filename in database.php correctly?

Comment: sry that was just type mistake here. in code its written correctly. By the way i don't think that path is needed anywhere during migration.

Comment: Can you check with this code `<?php print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); ?>`

Comment: Set host to: `'host'      => 'localhost',`

Comment: yeah its showing - Array ( [0] => sqlite [1] => mysql [2] => pgsql [3] => sqlite2 [4] => oci ) 1.

Comment: Okay, check your database pdo connections username/password/... and set to database password, set hostname to localhost. This problem is connecting to database (host to database can't find to connect).

Comment: actually in host file its -"myproject" not "localhost".

Comment: database pdo connections ? how i will check it ?

Comment: ya, i did it, but its showing same error - "Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'medismoCRM' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". i think better i should back up and remove the old project -"medismoCRM" database.

Comment: Change to `localhost`. Set a password of database, and try reinstall and check database configuration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34875/discussion-between-marin-sagovac-and-user1638279)